# How to increase font of axis and labels in factorplot in Seaborn in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, seaborn

I have plot like below using below code, nevertheless how can I increase fontsize of axis and labels on this plot ? It is small and therefore unreadable.
`sns.set(font_scale=1)` does not work

```
sns.factorplot(data = data,
               x = 'Month',
               y = "Sales", 
               col = 'StoreType', 
               palette = 'plasma',
               hue = 'StoreType',
               row = 'Promo') 
#sns.set(font_scale=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Use `sns.set(font_scale=1)` _before_ you plot anything

Comment: That's true @DavidG but also `font_scale=1` won't change the scaling (it's multiplicative). Paradoxially, @bruno845, the best way to solve your problem is probably to make the plot smaller; the text is small because Jupyter is shrinking the whole figure to fit in the allotted space. Try `height=3`.